# Select last element of a class in a list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Basically, I have a list that is generated dinamically with elements of different types and I need to select the last element for every type.

Example:

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ccc">First element of type ccc</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ccc">Second element of type ccc</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ccc">Third element of type ccc</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ddd">First element of type ddd</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ddd">Second element of type ddd</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb eee">First element of type eee</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to select the last element of every type.

I tried to play with :last/:last-child/:last-of-type but I think that I miss something or that I didn't find the right combination.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript for this

Comment: Do you want to select EVERY third element of ccc and EVERY second element of ddd or only the third and second element of the respective classes?

Comment: I need to select the last element for every type. 
The last of ccc, the last of ddd and the last of eee.

Answer (score 1):

Well here are the methods to select them but as you can see they are static. I recommend using javascript, do this: `document.getElementsByClassName('ccc')[2]` would return the third .ccc element. Learn more for DOM traversing and [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

```css
.aaa:nth-child(3) .ccc {
color:red;
}
.aaa:nth-child(5) .ddd {
color:green;
}
.aaa:nth-child(6) .eee {
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ccc">First element of type ccc</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ccc">Second element of type ccc</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ccc">Third element of type ccc</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ddd">First element of type ddd</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb ddd">Second element of type ddd</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
      <li class="aaa">
         <a class="bbb eee">First element of type eee</a>
         <table class="zzz"></table>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```